# Getting multiple properties from a variable

Tags: xcode, swift, class, properties

I need some help figuring out how to get a property from a variable in the easiest way possible.

So, right now I have this class below that sets up various properties of the blocks.

```
    class Block {

    var Name:String = "Block Name"
    var Value:Int = 0

    init (){
    }
}
    var grassBlock = Block()
    var dirtBlock = Block()
```

For an example I will include what I did to individually set up the name component of each block:

```
    grassBlock.Name = "Grass"
    dirtBlock.Name = "Dirt"
    grassBlock.Value = 10
    dirtBlock.Value = 5
```

Then I have some code that determines the "currentBlock" depending on various things. So to make it easy I will just say that:

```
    currentBlock = grassBlock.Name
```

Once I have the currentBlock variable set the to the grassBlock is there any way that I could grab the grassBlock.Value from it somehow so that this would work:

```
   currentBlockValue = currentBlock.Value
```

I would like to be able to just detect the current block and then have access to each of its properties if that is possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to create an object is by using the init constructor as below:

```
class Block {

    var Name:String?
    var Value:Int?

    init (name:String,value:Int){
        self.Name = name
        self.Value = value

    }


}
```

Creating objects can be done so easy like :

```
var grassBlock = Block(name: "Grass", value: 10)
var dirtBlock = Block(name: "Dirt", value: 5)
```

Here you are assigning object to object, And then use it to take the name or value property :

```
let currentBlock = grassBlock
let currentBlockValue = currentBlock.Value
let currentBlockName = currentBlock.Name
```

Comment: Thank u so much! Just what I was looking for :)